# Get file size from TFTP Server using JAVA without downloading the file

Tags: java, tftp

Is there a way to get the file size on a TFTP server without downloading the file. I want an JAVA API for the same if available.

I tried TFTPClient, but it does not support.

Note: I am able to get the file size on local tftp server, but not on the remote tftp. For the local below code works:

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
SocketAddress sockAddr = new InetSocketAddress(address.getHostAddress(),
                                               portNumber);
socket.connect(sockAddr);
File file = new File(fileName);
long fileSize = getFileSize(file);
if (fileSize > 0) {
    return fileSize;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. FTP I am able to. I am looking only for TFTP.

Answer (score 1):

The TFTP protocol (as specified in [RFC 1350](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1350)) does not support this.

Note that RFC 1350 has been enhanced with the ability to negotiate options; see the "updated by" list in the RFC.  However none of these updates provide a way to request the file size.

So the answer is that there is no way using a compliant TFTP server.

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephen.